# Memory in autorelease pool not deallocated until memory warning or app enters background

Tags: iphone, ios5, memory-management

I have a question regarding autorelease pool and memory deallocation in an app I'm working on. If anyone needs to see the code I can post it.

First and foremost I'm using ARC in this app, now basically I'm allocating a good bit of memory on start up (images for an intro animation), and the memory they take up doesn't seem to properly deallocate until I receive a memory warning for one reason or another, or if I enter the background and re-enter the foreground of the app.

I've been monitoring the amount of memory being allocated in code as well as in instruments so it seems that this issue isn't some false positive. I know for a fact I'm properly disposing of the image memory as I clearly set the UIImageView.animationImages property to nil as well as set the UIImageView to nil and release it's parent view controller from memory once the animation is done. Basically, everything it has to do with is set to nil or removedFromSuperview to be sure that ARC knows it should be released.

Is there any way I can purge this autoreleased memory pool similar to the result of entering the background of the app or receiving a memory warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, the UIImages I was allocating for my intro animation were being cached via imageNamed: method, therefore were retained even after they were autoreleased for some time.

To fix this I'm using imageWithContentsOfFile: method which does not cache the images.